# Objective-c To the power of a negative

Tags: objective-c, exponent

Write a program that evaluates the expression

```
3.31 × 10^(-8) + 2.01 × 10^(-7) ÷ 7.16 × 10^(-6) + 2.01 × 10^(-8)
```

**Answer**

```
float result;

result = (3.31 * 10.0e + 2.01 * 10.0e-8) / (7.16 * 10.0e-6 + 2.01 * 10.0e-8);

NSLog(@"%e",result);
```

This is the answer I found but please explain the exponents part and why i need the *`'e'`* also is there any other way of doing to the power of negative numbers. I tried doing it in other ways but it didn't work

Comment: Are You sure this the answer?

Comment: It should be result = (3.31 * 10.0e-8 + 2.01 * 10.0e-7) / (7.16 * 10.0e-6 + 2.01 * 10.0e-8);

Comment: Oh yeah I missed that. But why do you put 10.0e-8 for 10^(-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C (and by extension, Objective-C), 3×10<sup>5</sup> is written `3e5`. It's simply how scientific notation is expressed in C. Therefore, you can write:

```
float result = 3.31e-8 + 2.01e-7 / 7.16e-6 + 2.01e-8;
NSLog(@"%e", result);
```

Note that your expression in C should only have parentheses if your original mathematic expression did as well.

Comment: But why does only %e work? For nslog or is just how it is

Answer (score 1):

Use double, not float. float only gives you less than 8 digits precision at best. Unless you can explain with some good reason why you are using float, use double.

The traditional way to write numbers in "scientific format", in C since about 1970, but a lot earlier in FORTRAN, is 3.31E-8 for the first of your numbers, 2.01E-7 for the second and so on.

So:

```
double result = 3.31E-8 + 2.01E-7 / 7.16E-6 + 2.01E-8;
```

The parentheses that you wrote are wrong. Or your original formula is wrong, can't say which one.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about the parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

The Answer must be

> result = (3.31e-8 + 2.01e-7) / (7.16e-6 + 2.01e-8);

You can use this [stack exchange link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6273/what-does-e-mean-in-9-0122222900391e-5) to understand better.
In order to use less characters, instead of `10^(-8)` or anything else programmers should write `10.0e-8`.

**Thats the best way to solve it.**

Comment: Thanks for the link, it explained it a lot!